# git diff not showing the difference after untar the package

Tags: git, jenkins, tar

I have a `project_1.0.3.356.tar.gz` file. I will need to untar this file then commit to my git repo.

I am pretty sure the code is changed. But when I untar the file and try the command below, it did not detect any changes.

All the code is included in the tar file(`project_1.0.3.356.tar.gz`). It has multiple folders.

The steps are :

import package from sftp server,

untar the package

then doing the following shell command.

```
git init
git remote add origin gitrepo
git pull origin master
git add .
git diff
git status
git commit -a -m "test"
git push origin master
```

Comment: When are you doing the untar?

Comment: Can you indicate which command exactly gives you output different from what you expect or hope? Can you also indicate where and when in your command sequence you untar the tar file?

Comment: @FedericoNafria i am doing the untar before all these git command

Comment: @joanis Hi, the package has a src folder that contains multiple folders. i want to see inside these folders which program file has changed... but now it does not show anything changed. it says "nothing to commit" / "Already uptodate"

Comment: Maybe your `git pull` destroys the local contents? Try replacing it with `git fetch origin master` and then doing `git diff origin/master` instead?

Comment: @joanis  sounds promising... let me try

Comment: @joanis looks like it is still not fixing anything.. i have to do a pull before a push

Comment: @Rachel: did the `git diff origin/master` show any differences when you did `fetch` instead of `pull`? If so, I think I can write up a solution to your problem. To be more precise, if you do `git init`, `git remote add origin gitrepo`, `git fetch origin master` and then just `git diff` without any of the other commands, and the diff shows the differences you expect, then I know how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the order of your operations: first checkout the Repo, and then untar the files from the tar ball onto it:

```
git clone gitrepo
tar -xzf project_1.0.3.356.tar.gz
cd <projectdir>
git diff
```

This will only work correctly if the tar ball uses the same root directory name as is created by the `git clone`, so you may have to rename the directory to match between the two operations.

The general idea of this approach is that you first clone (and therefore checkout) the current state from your Git server, then you untar the file on top of it, changing all the files locally.

If the `git diff` shows the change you expect, you can perform the commit and push:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m test
git push
```